# Pass a string through onClick function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to pass a string in the onClick event handler function's arguments.

I am not able to pass the string to the function, but I am able to pass the number integer to the function.

PHP:

```
echo '<tr style="background: #D6EAF8" class="clickable-row" OnClick="DisplayEnterOrderModal('.$order["id_order"].','.$order["id_customer"].','.$order[7].','"wanted to be passed"');"  value="'.$order["id_order"].'" > ';
```

Error:

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"wanted to be passed"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp32\www\EK\index.php on line 644
```

Comment: You don't need both single and double quotes.

Comment: try to use single quote $order["id_order"] to $order['id_order']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Replace '"wanted to be passed"' with "wanted to be passed". Remove extra ' ' single quotes.

Or just escape them \"wanted to be passed\"

I hope this will help you :-)

Answer (score -1):

echo

```
    echo '<tr style="background: #D6EAF8" class="clickable-row" OnClick="DisplayEnterOrderModal('.$order["id_order"].','.$order["id_customer"].','.$order[7].','."wanted to be passed"');"  value="'.$order["id_order"].'" > ';
```

Please try this one, I think this might work.